# Scripting SSH to reboot GrandStream phones

Tags: ssh, automation, scripting, plink

I work with hundreds of stand-alone devices on our network that can be accessed via SSH. I'm using a GrandStream GXP2200 phone as an example here because it's the simplest to explain.

Our GrandStream GXP2200 phones can be accessed via SSH and you can perform basic functions over SSH, like rebooting or upgrading firmware. Rebooting a phone remotely using Putty is easy; just type the user and the password, type the reboot command, press y, then enter. The phone will then dutifully reboot.

I need to be able to script this. Ideally my script would be a batch file with one line per device, i.e.,

`plink -t admin@172.27.4.0 -pw <password> -m commands.txt`

`plink -t admin@172.27.4.1 -pw <password> -m commands.txt`

...etc.

I could have a script for firmware upgrades, reboots, or changing a specific setting, and then be able to deploy it to many devices. It seems like this should be easy, especially using something like Plink. I have a lot of experience on Windows, not as much on Linux. I'd really like to accomplish this on Windows, but I'm not opposed to spinning up an Ubuntu VM if I need to. I've read examples of using an `expect` script and a `bash` script and I've read about piping strings and putting the unicode character code in a text file and redirecting that in various ways... But nothing I've tried works.

The main issue is that there's no way to send the keystrokes needed to finish the command. For example, when the reboot command is sent to the phone over SSH, it will ask if you really want to reboot and if so to press y, then enter. In `commands.txt`, I can list a bunch of commands if I want, line by line. But if any of them require user interaction, it just gets stuck. For example, when the phone receives the `reboot` command, it prompts you to press `y` then `Enter`. From what I can tell, Plink doesn't have a way to send these keystrokes because it's waiting on the `reboot` command to complete before sending the next line from `commands.txt`.

The 2nd issue is that since these standalone network devices are fairly simple, the built-in commands (such as `reboot`) do not support options, such as `/y`. As a matter of fact, these phones completely stop parsing input from the terminal after detecting a valid command. For example, if I log on using Putty and type my command but add a bunch of random junk to the end, like `rebootlkq2jq3pyjq` and hit enter, it does the same as if I only typed `reboot`.

The only method I can use to reboot phones remotely is to manually log in to the web interface and click on a reboot button. I can figure out HTML but when it comes to PHP or Java or whatever the web interface is using, I'm lost. I'd love to be able to utilize code from that button on the web interface.

TLDR: How do I send `y` and `Enter` after sending the `reboot` command through a scripted SSH connection? There is a huge number of people on the internet looking for a solution to this problem.

:: Edit ::

It looks like my best option in this case is `expect`. It appears to be designed to solve this type of problem. Unfortunately, `expect` for Windows is a joke.

1. Good documentation is nonexistent. It's either way too advanced, way too simple, incomplete, or obsolete.
2. Some downloads or versions don't include all the needed files.
3. `tcl` is unable to find ssh (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`) even though I can type `ssh` in any command prompt on this machine and it works fine and I have added my `tcl` path to my User `Path` and System `Path` environment variables and rebooted.
4. `tcl`/`expect` looks like it wants to work with `plink` (it doesn't complain about not being able to find the file), but no matter what options I try, it always says `The request is not supported.` The last command I tried was `spawn plink -ssh 172.27.4.0` and it returned `The request is not supported.`

So yeah I'm going to try Ubuntu. I'll write my results in an edit or an answer depending on the outcome.

Comment: [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is the canonical answer for "how do I automate this terminal interaction?". If your goal is to automate the web interface, you're looking at a different set of solutions (such as, for example, [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright)).

Comment: Alternately, there are ssh client libraries for most programming and scripting languages. If you know java or perl or python or something like one of those, it's straightforward to write a simple app that opens a shell or exec session and sends the data that you want to send.

Comment: @larsks thank you for pointing out expect. I was so fed up with it I was about to look for some other solution. Learning the syntax has been challenging, but it is a very powerful language.

Comment: @Kenster I wish I knew those languages. It would be super handy to put a gui in front of expect. Add that to my list of things to learn some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Goal:** To remotely reboot a network device over SSH using an automated script.

**Solution:** Use an `expect` script on a Linux machine.

**Working script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set pass "password"
log_user 1

send_user "...... BEGIN EXPECT SCRIPT ......\n"

foreach arg $argv {

        send_user "\nStarting on $arg\n"
        spawn ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@$arg
        
        expect {
            "assword: " {
                send -- "$pass\r"
                send_user "PASSWORD SENT\n"
            }
        }

        expect {
            ">" {
                send -- "reboot\r"
                send_user "REBOOT COMMAND SENT\n"
            }
                
            "denied" {
                send_user "\nBAD PASSWORD\n"
                continue
            }
        }

        expect {
            "continue" {
                send -- "y\r"
                send_user " Y KEYSTROKE SENT\n"
                sleep 2
            }

            "Rebooting..." {
                send_user "\nY NOT REQUIRED\n"
            }
            
            "Connection refused" {
                send_user "\nBROKEN CONNECTION ON $arg\n"
            }
        }

    send_user "Done with $arg\n.................................\n"

}

send_user "\n......  END EXPECT SCRIPT  ......\n"

exit
```

Using `expect` running on Ubuntu feels like the best solution for my case. I spent about 4 hours today trying to get `expect` to work on Windows (I was bitterly unsuccessful). So instead of using Windows, I spun up an Ubuntu 20 Server VM, installed `expect` with `sudo apt install expect`, used `autoexpect` to generate a script, edited that script, and I have already got a working script template in less than 1 hour. I didn't see any weird environment quirks or syntax issues in the Linux version. My Linux-foo isn't very strong, but I was able to figure it out fairly quickly.

I plan to scale this up not only for reboots, but also to script settings changes on a host of IP phones, network switches, network cameras, and probably a few Linux servers.